# tag h4 enclosed in div class

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have problems analyzing HTML elements with the "div" attribute using Beautifulsoup. The code looks like this

I need to extract what is inside the h4 tag, I could not search for the text 'Ocarrol' since it is a random value

```
find('div',{"class": "carResultRow_OfferInfo_Supplier-wrap "})
```

When making the query, I returned None

```html
<div class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_Supplier-wrap ">
<h3 class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_SupplierLabel">Servicio proporcionado por:</h3>
<img src="https://cdn2.rcstatic.com/images/suppliers/flat/ocarrol_logo.gif" title="Ocarrol" alt="Ocarrol">
<h4 style="" xpath="1">Ocarrol</h4>
<a href="InfoPo=0&amp;driversAge=30&amp;os=1" onclick="GAQPush('cboxElement">Términos y condiciones</a>
</div>
```

[link](https://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?enabler=&country=Argentina&doYear=2019&distance=10&ftsEntry=22776&city=Salta&driverage=on&doFiltering=false&filterName=CarCategorisationSupplierFilter&dropCity=Salta&dropFtsType=C&ftsAutocomplete=Salta%2C%20Salta%2C%20Argentina&driversAge=30&dropFtsAutocomplete=Salta%2C%20Salta%2C%20Argentina&dropFtsLocationName=Salta&fromLocChoose=true&filterTo=1000&dropLocationName=&dropCountryCode=&ftsType=C&doMinute=00&countryCode=&puYear=2019&ftsLocationSearch=161&dropFtsSearch=L&locationName=&puMinute=00&ftsInput=salta&doDay=29&searchType=allareasgeosearch&filterFrom=0&coordinates=-24.7833%2C-65.4167&puMonth=5&dropLocation=161&dropFtsInput=salta&doHour=10&dropCountry=Argentina&dropCoordinates=-24.7833%2C-65.4167&ftsLocationName=Salta&ftsSearch=L&puDay=26&dropFtsLocationSearch=161&puHour=10&location=161&dropFtsEntry=22776&doMonth=5&filterCoordinates=-24.79123%2C-65.40833%3A-24.79%2C-65.408%3A-24.7931%2C-65.41%3A-24.79103974%2C-65.40971696%3A-24.78988701%2C-65.40880545)

Add the link, I just need the name of the car company in this case Ocarrol, Ocarrol, Hertz, Fit Car Rental..etc

Comment: is there an url you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using BeautifulSoup 4.7+. Certain attributes are handled a bit special in Beautiful Soup, and in 4.7, the end result is a little different than it was in <= 4.6.

Attributes that are usually handled as space separated lists are handled a bit differently than all other attributes. `class` happens to be one of these attributes that is usually handled as space separated lists. BeautifulSoup actually stores these attributes not as they are in the HTML document, but actually stores them as a list of classes (spaces removed): `"class1 class2 "` -> `['class1', 'class2']`. When it needs to evaluate the class attribute as a string, it reassembles the class joining each value with a space between, but notice things like trailing spaces are no longer present: `"class1 class2"`.

Now, I'm not arguing this is an intuitive thing to do, only that this is what BeautifulSoup does. I personally would prefer that BeautifulSoup stores them as the original string, and then splits them into a list when needed, but that is not what they do.

Now in BeautifulSoup <= 4.6, the trailing space I believe gets preserved, but has a number of other quirks. But in your case, 4.7+, you just need to assume that trailing and leading spaces are ignored and that whitespace is collapsed to a single space between classes. So in your case, just leave off the trailing space.

```
soup.find('div',{"class": "carResultRow_OfferInfo_Supplier-wrap"})
```

You can read more about this behavior here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1824502.

---

Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_Supplier-wrap ">
<h3 class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_SupplierLabel">Servicio proporcionado por:</h3>
<img src="https://cdn2.rcstatic.com/images/suppliers/flat/ocarrol_logo.gif" title="Ocarrol" alt="Ocarrol">
<h4 style="" xpath="1">Ocarrol</h4>
<a href="InfoPo=0&amp;driversAge=30&amp;os=1" onclick="GAQPush('cboxElement">Términos y condiciones</a>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('div',{"class": "carResultRow_OfferInfo_Supplier-wrap"}).find('h4'))
```

Output

```
<h4 style="" xpath="1">Ocarrol</h4>
```

Comment: With or without space keeps returning me None

Comment: @Sebas79, I've posted an example that I have tested locally that works for me in my answer. If you are having issues, you'll have to post an example that isn't working.  What version of BeautifulSoup are you using? And does my working example not work for you?

Comment: This solution gives me everything as a result, and I just need what is on the h4 tags, above I leave the link

Comment: @Sebas79, I've updated with a solution that only selects the h4. I was mainly addressing the `None` issue, but I see you also want the `h4`. The adjusted solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CSS selector instead of find?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_Supplier-wrap ">
<h3 class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_SupplierLabel">Servicio proporcionado por:</h3>
<img src="https://cdn2.rcstatic.com/images/suppliers/flat/ocarrol_logo.gif" title="Ocarrol" alt="Ocarrol">
<h4 style="" xpath="1">Ocarrol</h4>
<a href="InfoPo=0&amp;driversAge=30&amp;os=1" onclick="GAQPush('cboxElement">Términos y condiciones</a>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(soup.select('div[class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_Supplier-wrap"]'))
```

prints:

```
[<div class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_Supplier-wrap">
<h3 class="carResultRow_OfferInfo_SupplierLabel">Servicio proporcionado por:</h3>
<img alt="Ocarrol" src="https://cdn2.rcstatic.com/images/suppliers/flat/ocarrol_logo.gif" title="Ocarrol"/>
<h4 style="" xpath="1">Ocarrol</h4>
<a href="InfoPo=0&amp;driversAge=30&amp;os=1" onclick="GAQPush('cboxElement">Términos y condiciones</a>
</div>]
```

Comment: Hi Andre, this solution gives me the result [ ]

Comment: Must be some minor bug in your version of BeautifulSoup. My verson `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1` and `lxml==4.3.3`